# Dynamically added rows to table does not the get the Dojo style

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dojo

I am working in ASP.Net MVC4 with Dojo. I have a strange problem when I am adding new rows to html table. I need to have a table which supports adding and removing rows and textboxes inside should have dojo style. I referred the post http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ ad tried to create the same thing. Let me explain my code. Below is my view

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Button"]);
    </script>
}
 <table id="servicesTable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label id="lblSelectService">
                        Select</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label id="lblServiceName">
                        Name</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label id="lblTitle">
                        AE Title</label>
                </th>

            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_ServiceRow", Model.Services[i])
            }
        </table>
```

My partial view for rendering each row is like below

```
@model WebUI.Models.RemDevServiceViewModel
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsMarked,
                     new { id = @String.Format("Service[{0}]IsMarked", @Model.ID) })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 100px; id="Service[@Model.ID]Name"
        name="Service[@Model.ID].Name" type="text"
                     data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" value="@Model.Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 100px;" id="Service[@Model.ID]Title" 
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                        name="Service[@Model.ID].Title" type="text" 
value="@Model.Title" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have an add button which will add new row to the table. The problem that I am facing is, new row does not get the dojo style and they are rendered as normal textboxes. Initially loaded rows are rendered as dojo style text boxes, but the newly added are not like that. My jquery function to add new rows is like below

```
function addNewService() {
    $.ajax({
        url: rootPath + "MyController/AddNewService",
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {

            $("#servicesTable tbody").append(html);
        },
        error: function (ts) {
            alert("Error while adding services");
        }
    });
}
```

Can any one tell me how to solve this? Please note that I am aware about the existence of Dojo grid. I want to take the advantage of model binding and hence following this style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the [parser](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html) over the added nodes. Are you seriously loading jquery on the page as well? Anyway, with the code you've got, it's kind of tricky to select the just added nodes, but if you put the following inside the success method it might work.

```
var newNodes = $(html).appendTo("#servicesTable tbody");
require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser){
    newNodes.forEach(function(node){
        parser.parse(node);
    });
});
```

If you parse over nodes that were already parsed, the parser will throw an error. Also, if you need to support older browsers you'll want to replace the forEach with a standard for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot David for your reply. Your code did not work exactly, but I got the idea and below code is working for me. Please dont feel that I am answering my own question. I want to format the code properly and hence using this view. Once again thanks a lot

```
success: function (html) {
        var newNodes = $(html).appendTo("#servicesTable tbody");
        require(["dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser"], function (array, parser) {
            array.forEach(newNodes, function (node, i) {
             parser.parse(node);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Corrected solution provided by David

Comment: I'm glad I could help =) it's also good to have a solution that definitely works here for anyone else who might encounter the same problem. =)